# Apache PHP-FPM Centos AH01071

Tags: php, apache, centos, virtualhost

I have a CentOS server and I am trying to configure apache with php-fpm. I have a virtualhost in a conf file. When checking the status of http and php-fpm all is fine but when trying to access the website in the browser,
I have errors based on the filesmatch part of my conf file :

```
 <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/path/to/docroot"
 </FilesMatch>

 => [proxy_fcgi:error]  AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'
 In the browser : File not found


 <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
 </FilesMatch>


         => [proxy_fcgi:error] AH01071: Got error 'Unable to open primary script: 
//path/to/docroot/index.php (No such file or directory)'
         In the browser: No input file specified
```

The /path/to/docroot also has apache permission, what could be the issue? any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I use this and it works: `SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"`

Comment: Thanks for your help @arkascha. If I am not mistaking, the sock file is created automatically after starting the php-fpm service and mine created the php-fpm.sock file  in /var/run folder and I don't see any other sock file in the system. I will try  to  change the folder of the sock file like in your case /run/php rather, maybe that is causing the issue. Thanks again

Comment: The location of that socket in the local file system is irrelevant. No reason to change the configured location. I just wanted to confirm that the syntax you are using is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the open_basedir and docroot settings in the php.ini. I modified the www.conf file inside php-fpm.d folder to add the two settings :

```
php_admin_value['open_basedir'] = /path/to/base_dir 
php_admin_value['doc_root'] = /path/to/doc_root
```

and then everything worked.

Thanks!